# Upgrading multiple modules at once crashes the process

Tags: 7, updating, upgrading

Just upgraded from 7.18 to 7.23 and selected to upgrade all modules and all I got is neverending 'Preparing to update your site' on Installing updates page on /authorize.php?batch=1&op=start&id=40

So what if I refresh page or something will the site crash or something?

UPDATE: It just crashed after like 20 minutes of nothing and I got this error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. Path: /authorize.php?batch=1&id=40&op=do StatusText: Service unavailable (with message) ResponseText: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: DELETE FROM {queue} WHERE (item_id = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 8656 ) in SystemQueue->deleteItem() (line 273 of /modules/system/system.queue.inc).Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: UPDATE {batch} SET batch=:db_update_placeholder_0 WHERE (bid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] =&gt; a:12:{s:4:&quot;sets&quot;;a:1:{i:0;a:15:{s:7:&quot;sandbox&quot;;a:0:{}s:7:&quot;results&quot;;a:2:{s:3:&quot;log&quot;;a:1:{s:5:&quot;views&quot;;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:&quot;message&quot;;s:57:&quot;Installed &lt;em class=&quot;placeholder&quot;&gt;views&lt;/em&gt; successfully&quot;;s:7:&quot;success&quot;;b:1;}}}s:5:&quot;tasks&quot;;a:0:{}}s:7:&quot;success&quot;;b:0;s:5:&quot;start&quot;;d:1377856599.71076107025146484375;s:7:&quot;elapsed&quot;;i:0;s:5:&quot;title&quot;;s:18:&quot;Installing updates&quot;;s:12:&quot;init_message&quot;;s:40:&quot;Preparing to update your site&lt;br/&gt;&amp;nbsp;&quot;;s:8:&quot;finished&quot;;s:38:&quot;update_authorize_update_batch_finished&quot;;s:4:&quot;file&quot;;s:35:&quot;modules/update/update.authorize.inc&quot;;s:16:&quot;progress_message&quot;;s:29:&quot;Completed @current of @total.&quot;;s:13:&quot;error_message&quot;;s:22:&quot;An error has occurred.&quot;;s:3:&quot;css&quot;;a:0:{}s:5:&quot;total&quot;;i:12;s:5:&quot;count&quot;;i:12;s:5:&quot;queue&quot;;a:2:{s:4:&quot;name&quot;;s:17:&quot;drupal_batch:40:0&quot;;s:5:&quot;class&quot;;s:10:&quot;BatchQueue&quot;;}}}s:16:&quot;has_form_submits&quot;;b:0;s:11:&quot;current_set&quot;;i:0;s:11:&quot;progressive&quot;;b:1;s:3:&quot;url&quot;;s:36:&quot;/authorize.php?batch=1&quot;;s:11:&quot;url_options&quot;;a:0:{}s:10:&quot;source_url&quot;;s:0:&quot;&quot;;s:8:&quot;redirect&quot;;s:28:&quot;/authorize.php&quot;;s:5:&quot;theme&quot;;s:5:&quot;seven&quot;;s:17:&quot;redirect_callback&quot;;s:11:&quot;drupal_goto&quot;;s:2:&quot;id&quot;;s:2:&quot;40&quot;;s:13:&quot;error_message&quot;;s:110:&quot;Please continue to &lt;a href=&quot;/authorize.php?batch=1&amp;amp;id=40&amp;amp;op=finished&quot;&gt;the error page&lt;/a&gt;&quot;;} [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 40 ) in _batch_shutdown() (line 537 of /includes/batch.inc).
```

Comment: First, see if there are errors in webserwer's log. Second, you do have backups? Third: we need to see an error log from MySQL too, now when we know it's MySQL dying. And test your tables for health.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have drush try running drush updatedb.

Errors you are getting you should restore backup of your site and update modules one by one.

You can also login phpmyadmin and try to optimize and cleanup mysql if you don't have a copy as it seems your db is crashing and it could be pending database updates. If you don't have drush try going to yoursite.com/update.php to run db updates.

If at all possible use drush for managing your site gives you option to update as well as rollback any updates.

Comment: can I use drush on windows 8 x64?

Comment: @user13176 if you can install PHP CLI on it, yes. I do. But that does not change the fact that now you should try to check your database's error log to be sure. *"optimize and cleanup"* pgrujic mentioned.